# Dental Braces : Urgent Advise Needed

Tags: tooth-decay, brushing-teeth, cavity, mouthwash, dental-braces

I got braces in January 2017. It is today 12 March 2017 that I got one of the braces detached from tooth (Lower tooth and Second Left tooth with respect to my reference frame).

I talked to my Dentist and He is our of Town and will be available after 3 days. Dentist said - " Leave it as it is. It will cause no harm."

But I suspect, since food and water (Water is hard at my area)  can get between tooth and the bracket, And 3 days are enough for cavity to dominate. Is my tension worth? If yes, Please suggest some methods to avoid cavity

*I brush twice a day and I use Hexidine mouthwash. *

I planned to pull that bracket a little and clean the area between it and the tooth. It is right?

Comment: You'll be fine. I've had brackets break off and as long as you keep the area where the bracket should be, clean, you'll be fine. If your orthodontist thinks the area isn't clean enough, he/she can clean it before re-cementing it.

Comment: @L.B. thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the bracket is removed all the way and is not cemented you can remove it carefully. You should be fine but I have had this happen before. Just open the tiny latch on the bracket and place bracket in a safe place. If you cannot remove it mouthwash and a little floss or a Christmas tree brush will help clean behind it.

Comment: Bracket is not removed. It is held in place by the wire since other braces are intact. Thus, the damaged bracket is sliding over the wire.

Comment: You can remove the bracket it will not harm anything